# How to add logging to a jdbc pollar adapter

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am trying to implement BeanPostProcessor to return my own JdbcPollingChannelAdapter that will help me to add some logging and know about polling activity. I have some code below, please help to complete this or if there is a better way.

Thanks

```
public class CustomAdapter extends JdbcPollingChannelAdapter {

private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAdapter .class);

public CustomJdbcPollingChannelAdapter(DataSource dataSource, String selectQuery)
{
    super(dataSource, selectQuery);        
}

@Override
public Message<Object> receive()
{
    Message<Object> polledData =  super.receive();
    if(polledData == null || polledData.getPayload() == null)
    logger.info("received no data..............");
    return polledData;

}
```

}

public class MyPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

```
private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyPostProcessor .class);

public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)throws BeansException
{
    /* not able to figure what goes here for this to work.
    logger.info(bean+"..................."+beanName);
    if(bean instanceof org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean)
    {
        //SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean bean = (SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean)bean;
        //bean...??
        return bean;
    }
    else
    {
     return bean;
    }
    */
    return bean;
}


public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)throws BeansException
{
    //logger.info(bean+"................................................."+beanName);
    return bean;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` is a `MessageSource<?>` and it is a component to be used from active `endpoint` - `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`, which has this code:

```
if (message == null) {
    if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()){
        this.logger.debug("Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'");
    }
    result = false;
}
else {
    if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            this.logger.debug("Poll resulted in Message: " + message);
    }
    if (holder != null) {
        holder.setMessage(message);
    }
    this.handleMessage(message);
    result = true;
}
```

So, isn't it enough for you to just configure `org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter` logging category?

From other side, there are no stops to use your custom `MessageSource<?>` implementation and `BeanPostProcessor` is really an overhead. You just need to configure your `CustomAdapter` as a generic `<bean>` and use it from another generic bean definition - `SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean`.

Right, with that customization you lose the Spring Integration XML power. But who said that XML is a panacea - [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference)?

**UPDATE**

Since you have a custom `MessageSource<?>` you can use it directly from:

```
<bean id="jdbcSource" class="com.my.proj.adapter.CustomAdapter">
   <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
   <constructor-arg value="SELECT * FROM foo"/>
   <property name="updateSql" value="UPDATE foo set status=1 where id in (:id)"/>
</bean>

<int:inbound-channel-adapter ref="jdbcSource" channel="jdbcPollingChannel"/>
```

Any protocol-specific `<*:inbound-channel-adapter>` is just for convenience, but they all do them same as default one.

Comment: The log level does not help as i have several polling adapters running and to help support/monitor this application i need to log the name of the component etc. I can use it as generic <bean> but will it allow me to use other feature of polling adapter, transactions and update sql?

Comment: It doesn't matter: Spring Integration XML is parsed and populated as beans, e.g. `<jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>` populates `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` and `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` to `poll` from the first one.

Comment: Could you give a example or hint how would i replace a <int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter ..configuration to make use of my own custom adapter above, thanks

Comment: Added sample to the answer

Comment: Approve the answer then! :-)

Comment: Sure, i was unaware, i am still trying to get used to this place, thanks. The solution given me endless possibilities for several other things i am trying to do using SI.